# Where can i design and modify a new mail template for sending emails to users when commenting?

Tags: theme-development, admin, email

the mail sent by Wordpress is ok but its template is very simple and has no style or even a header or footer! its message has no information about my blog or logo. where can i edit its message body and/or where can i style this template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several plugins to accomplish this.

Like 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-better-emails/ 
or
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-email-template/